# Test Neo4J Plugin

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-plugin

I am very new to Neo4J, and all I want is to create a simple plug-in to return

```
"Hello World!"
```

I know Neo4j uses Cypher to query the database and I took the sample from their website to create the plugin, but how can I actually call my test method to see that it actually displays the message?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.neo4j.org/learn

The (free) eBook has a section on testing plugins and extensions.